# Notifications not being sent to external recipients after embedded sign

Tags: docusignapi

Could use a little bit of assistance with a relatively complex envelope.

I need to do the following:

1. Generate an envelope from a template
2. Perform an embedded sign as the first signature
3. Once the embedded sign is done, send out 2 external signature requests.

Steps 1 and 2 are working beautifully. The user is redirected to the docusign embedded signing page, and then back to my application. Step 3 is not. I am not getting any email notifications for signers 2 and 3 (who should receive a link via email) even after the embedded sign is complete. I am using the C# SDK.

Currently I am generating the envelope as follows:

```
        EnvelopeDefinition env = new EnvelopeDefinition
        {
            TemplateId = document.TemplateID,
            TemplateRoles = document.Signers.Select(s => new TemplateRole()
            {
                Email = s.Email,
                Name = s.Name,
                RoleName = s.Role,
                ClientUserId = s.Email,
                EmailNotification = !s.ExternalSign
                    ? new RecipientEmailNotification()
                    {
                        EmailSubject = "NG",
                        EmailBody = "Hello, please sign these documents so we can begin testing"
                    }
                    : null,
                
            }).ToList(),
            Notification = new Notification()
            {
                Reminders = new Reminders("5", "true", "7")
            },
            Status = "sent"
        };
```

And Sending the envelope as follows:

```
            var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(ApiClient);
            var result = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(AccountId, envelopeDefinition);
            envelope.EnvelopeId = result.EnvelopeId;

            var externalSigner = document.Signers.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ExternalSign);
            if (externalSigner is not null)
            {
                var viewRequest = MakeRecipientViewRequest(externalSigner.Email, externalSigner.Name, ReturnUrl + returnUrlSuffix);
                var viewResult = envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(AccountId, result.EnvelopeId, viewRequest);
                envelope.EmbeddedSignURL = viewResult.Url;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one line:

```
ClientUserId = s.Email
```

You should ONLY have for embedded signers.

It appears you loop through all signers and that's your issue.

Only these you want embedded need this line and then they won't get an email sent to them.